# Macro with regular expression

Tags: macros, l3regex

I want to use \def or something similar so that every time I write `\n`, with `n` a number, it converts to `\textbf{n}`. I know I can use `\def` with arguments and that would be a workaround but I'm curious if what I want can be achieved using regular expressions.

I'm imagining something like `\def\regexp{\n}{\textbf{\1}}`.

For example, I'd like to type `\12345` to get `\textbf{12345}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Don't do this!!!**

But to answer the question:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\0{\zz0}\def\1{\zz1}\def\2{\zz2}\def\3{\zz3}\def\4{\zz4}
\def\5{\zz5}\def\6{\zz6}\def\7{\zz7}\def\8{\zz8}\def\9{\zz9}
\def\zz{\bgroup\bfseries\afterassignment\zzz\count0= }
\def\zzz{\the\count0\egroup}
\begin{document}

\1\  and \456, and \22.

1  and 456, and 22.

\end{document}
```

Comment: huh, I thought that by doing that you'd have to type `\1\2`....

Comment: @GuillermoMosse no the afterassignment grabs a whole number but this is so far from being usable syntax it is, I hope, only of academic interest.

Comment: Of course :-). But your solution isn't complete, right? You'd have to add a line of code for every new length of a number

Comment: @GuillermoMosse no have you tried it?  `\165463` works as posted.

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood your code. Reading \zzz made me think that you could use it for 3 characters max